# Request for tag: [blazemeter]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-creation

I recently [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092599/jmeter-jenkins-and-blazemeter-to-rag-pass-fail-and-rank-the-performance-of-a-b/17104295#17104295) that was related to the BlazeMeter website, and wanted to add the blazemeter tag to it, but am lacking the 1500 reputation needed to create it.
Can someone please help with this?

On an even more meta level, why don't we have a tag request page? where people can come and request tags, and maybe even vote on them?

Thanks

Comment: [Here you go!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazemeter)

Comment: The tag [meta-tag:tag-request] is for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I recently answered a question that was related to the BlazeMeter
>   website, and wanted to add the blazemeter tag to it, but am lacking
>   the 1500 reputation needed to create it. Can someone please help with
>   this?

[image]

> On an even more meta level, why don't we have a tag request page?
>   where people can come and request tags, and maybe even vote on them?

We already have such a page. The tag [tag-request](/questions/tagged/tag-request) is exactly for that purpose.